# System.Timer as a Singleton

Tags: c#, multithreading, design-patterns, timer, singleton

I have data which is constantly being read by many threads. This data needs to be updated daily.

My approach has been to use a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` to manage access to the data. Every night the first thread to detect the day change applies a `WriteLock` to the data and updates it.

In order to avoid the constant check for the day change event. I would ideally like to create a System.Timer object as a singleton and have it automatically start and then execute every 24hrs thereafter.

This has been my approach:

First I extended System.Timers to execute the callback on init.

```
using System.Timers;

namespace Utilities
{
    class AutoStartTimer : Timer
    {
        public AutoStartTimer(ElapsedEventHandler callback, int period):base(period)
        {
            callback(null, null);
            AutoReset = true;
            Elapsed += callback;
            Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I declared it at a singleton where I needed it.

```
private static AutoStartTimer _loadDataTimer = 
                                new AutoStartTimer(DataLoader, 86400000); // Daily
```

This approach is working for me so far. However I would like to know if there are any better ways to implement a Singleton Timer which executes once on initialisation and then for a set period afterwards or if anyone has managed to do this more efficiently without extending the Timer class.

I need to use many of these in my current project so I want to make sure I am using a good approach.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not add a static Timer instance to another class which manages that instance?

Comment: Wouldn't that require a check to initilise/whether the timer is null  every time I created an instance of that class?

Comment: How would using a timer prevent the concurrency issues?

Comment: I'm using locks for concurrency. The timer is to avoid checking the time.

Comment: I have added what I believe Davo was suggesting to the end of the question. - Haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a static class:

```
public static class DayManager
{
     public static readonly object SyncRoot = new object();

     private static readonly Timer dayTimer;

     static DayManager()
     {
         dayTimer = new Timer { AutoReset = true; Enabled = true; Interval = 86400000d };
         dayTimer.Elapsed += OnDayTimerElapsed;
     }

     protected void OnDayTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
     {
         if(DayPassedEvent != null)
         {
             DayPassedEvent(this, null);
         }
     }

     public event EventHandler DayPassedEvent;
}
```

Now, in each of the threads you should subscribe to the DayPassedEvent and use Monitor.TryEnter(DayManager.SyncRoot) to acquire a lock on the timer managing class. This means that only one thread should go on to try to update the data and the rest should fail to get the lock and continue with their lives. I'll leave the exact implementation of this up to you.

Alternatively, you could remove the SyncRoot from the timer managing class here and use another as you're already doing, I just provided it for reference only.

Comment: I don't need to to run on day elapsed just 24hr intervals... I do however like the solution as a way to have the updates happen at a specific time. Thanks!

Comment: Well, the wording is awkward as it doesn't run at 0:00, but it just runs every 24hrs. When I provide example solutions I don't pay a lot of attention to appropriate naming. :D

Comment: Just noticed that myself. Solution was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Instance methods and variables in a static class?

Answer (score 1):

I have better approach for you. Use Codeplex's Lightweight Scheduler library.

A lightweight task scheduling library that allows you to easily schedule the invocation of callback methods at specified times or intervals. Supports .NET 3.5 and Silverlight.

The library allows you to include flexibule scheduling functionality into your application with just a few lines of code, and provides a fluent API to configure jobs:

Link:
http://scheduling.codeplex.com/

Other approaches:

Task Scheduler Class in .NET:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx

http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1763/Task-Scheduler-Library-for-NET